# Q.js is not responding if focus of the Excel TPA (edge webview) changed while executing multiple async calls

Tags: javascript, office-js, microsoft-edge, office-addins, q

We are using Office.js version 1.1 and q.js version 1.5.1 in our excel add-in application.

Excel TPA is loading successfully if we maintain excel application as active.
But if move to any other application  at the time Excel TPA loading is in progress, async calls execution are getting stopped with out any error ( 'then' or 'fail' methods are not getting executed of Q promise).

we tested in multiple systems with different configuration and we observed only windows version 1909 has this issue.

can we do any thing to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Could this be the phenomenon described in the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-troubleshooting#api-limitations-when-the-active-workbook-switches

Comment: I can see in the table that you are using Edge legacy and Edge Chromium both kinds of browsers. I want to confirm with you, are you also using the webview2 (Chromium) along with web view(edge HTML)? Does the issue occur with any other control if you do not use a web view in the add-in?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT : we are getting this issue with web view. system which are having IE are working fine.

Comment: @RickKirkham : we are able to handle focus changed exceptions on moving one active excel to another active excel, by doing retry operations. but problem here is we are not getting any exceptions if move to other application.

Comment: @SaiKumar, I can see that many technologies are involved in this issue that makes this issue more complicated. Memory dump analysis is needed to find the root cause of the issue. If you need further support on this issue then I suggest you create a Microsoft support ticket using [this link](https://support.serviceshub.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness/onboarding). Please note that this is a **paid support** service. Thanks for your understanding.